# Keep the state of a checkbox while changing between forms

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have form1 which has a command button that opens form2 which then has some checkboxes. When i run the program form1 comes up first and i click on the command button to go to form2,then i click on one of the check boxes and if i go back to form1 and back again to form2 the checkbox is changing its state to unchecked again. How can i keep the state of it at "Checked"?
The only piece of code i have is from the command button from from1.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Form4 form4 = new Form4();
    form4.Show();       
}
```

Comment: This isn't C, check your tags.

Comment: Is this C or C#? Only tag as one or explain why both.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think about this kind of problem is to separate the UI (the "view") from the state of the data being edited by the application (the "model").

Have the state stored in, say, a class instance that is available to both forms.  Bind the state of the checkbox in each form to the state of the boolean property representing the checked state in that class instance.

Depending on your UI technology in use, there is better or lesser support for binding a model property to a UI element that represents the value of that property.  There's good support in WPF and Silverlight.  WinForms doesn't provide good support out of the box, but there are third party libraries that add decent support, or you can manually hook up the state of the checkbox to the state of the boolean property backing that state using event handlers.

This is part of the pattern known as MVC, or Model-View-Controller.

Comment: Thank you Eric i get what you mean,any suggested code?Or some link maybe would be great. I just started C# and i havent got any experience in programing!

Comment: @KostasMar: If you are programming WinForms by choice, don't.  Use a more modern UI framework like Metro or WPF.  If you are required to use WinForms, have a look at this MVC framework for WinForms: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp.  It is decent, though not as powerful as the support in WPF.  Also, read about MVC in general.  Good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller